# Assign static value to GridLength resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridlength

**Case**

I've defined a series of GridLenghts as a resource in my WPF Window:

```
<w:GridLength x:Key="ScrollBarRowHeight">17</w:GridLength>
```

Since this scrollbar height is variable dependent on the operating system used, I'd like to refactor this line of code to use the static parameter value [SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.horizontalscrollbarheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Problem**

I've tried both these lines:

```
<w:GridLength x:Key="ScrollBarRowHeight"><DynamicResource Key="{x:Static System.Windows.SystemParameters.CaptionHeightKey}" /></w:GridLength>
<w:GridLength x:Key="ScrollBarRowHeight"><x:Static x:Key="System.Windows.SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight" /></w:GridLength>
```

Resulting both in the same compile-time error:

```
Cannot add content to object of type 'System.Windows.GridLength'.
```

**Questions**

- Is it possible to do this declaratively in XAML?
- If yes, how?
- If no, is there a neat solution which does not include code-behind?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use the `SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` value directly instead of trying to duplicate it?

Comment: @Sheridan, how do I use it directly?

Comment: What control property do you want to use it for?

Comment: I'll use it for the control property RowDefinition.Height. The thing is, I reference the resource a lot and like to define it on top of the XAML file.

Comment: And how exactly would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering why don't you just use the `SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` value directly in your XAML, instead of trying to duplicate its value? (Added from comment)

On the [`SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.horizontalscrollbarheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page that *you* provided a link to, there is a code example which shows you exactly how to use the various `SystemParameters` properties in both XAML *and* code:

```
<Button FontSize="8" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"      
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}"
     Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.IconGridWidth}">
     SystemParameters
</Button>

...

Button btncsharp = new Button();
btncsharp.Content = "SystemParameters";
btncsharp.FontSize = 8;
btncsharp.Background = SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush;
btncsharp.Height = SystemParameters.CaptionHeight;
btncsharp.Width = SystemParameters.IconGridWidth;
cv2.Children.Add(btncsharp);
```

From the linked page:

> In XAML, you can use the members of SystemParameters as either a static property usage, or a dynamic resource references (with the static property value as the key). Use a dynamic resource reference if you want the system based value to update automatically while the application runs; otherwise, use a static reference. Resource keys have the suffix Key appended to the property name.

So if you want the values to update while the application is running, then you *should* be able to use these properties in a `Binding` like this:

```
<Button FontSize="8" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"      
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}}"
     Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.IconGridWidth}}">
     SystemParameters
</Button>
```

---

You *should* also be able to use it as a `DynamicResource` in this way:

```
Property="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}}"
```